# connecting 3.3V to +3V

Tags: electronics, components, voltage-protection

Well, I hope this question won' t be buried to the dark depths of this forum as my previous q' s:) But I suppose it won' t this time cause it's pretty short without this introduction part...

I have an Arduino pro mini works with 3.3V and in the other hand, I have a DS1307 DIP ic, works with +3V. I was wondering if I could connect the ic to my Arduino directly.

Thats all. Thanks already:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 3V input on the DS1307 is for a 3V battery, usually a CR2032 or similar. The *supply* voltage of the DS1307 is 5V, which means that it won't work with a 3.3V Arduino without a separate supply and level shifter.

Comment: Seems like Konko would be better off finding an RTC capable of operating on a 3.3v supply.  The present device might be usable with the upsteam source if the 3.3v Arduino is regulating down from something around 5v, but then an I2C level shifter would be needed, probably MOSFET-based.

Comment: Minimal supply voltage for the DS1307 is 4.5V

Comment: The supply voltage is specified as 5V±10%, but it's really intended to be used with as reasonably precise a 5V supply as you can get.

Comment: Thank you all, I have a 5v to 3.3v converter, I' m probably gonna use ic with that. I' m happy that I' ve learnt that DS1307 works with 5 volts...